# How to copy a variable of type Object

Tags: java

Have a variable is defined as:

```
Class MyClass extends Someclass {
    private Object variable;

    public MyClassInfo(BestObject bestObject) {
        super(bestObject);

        if(variable != null) {
            //how do I copy variable?
        }
    }
}
```

I am wondering how do I copy a variable since its type is `Object`?

Comment: You can only copy objects which support some sort of copy function.  (Or did you mean you want to copy the *reference* to the object?)

Comment: This is what I want, but since its Object I don't know how to copy it, like I am doing in this case 
if(value.getExpirationDate() != null) {
                expirationDate = new Date(value.getExpirationDate().getTime());
            }

Comment: You'll need to provide more information.  Why are you declaring `variable` as an `Object` and some other type?  Where and how is `variable` set?  What possible runtime types could `variable` be?  What are you trying to copy it into?  What's going on in general?

Comment: If you believe the object to actually be of another class (a subclass of Object) you can interrogate it's class with `instanceof` or by doing `variable.getClass().getName()`.  Then you can "cast" the reference to one of the correct type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the "Object" variable *might* actually be a Double, eg:

```
if (variable instanceof Double) {
   Double doubleVar = (Double) variable;
   int intVal = doubleVar.intValue();
   // Use the intVal.
}
```

But, of course, if you only want to know how to "save" the object pointer for later reference, simply do:

```
Object savedVariable = variable;
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you don't know whether the object *lets* you copy it (it could be a singleton), or what the copy method might be, all you can do in this case is copy the reference to it.